# ExpanderView Header width to 100%

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've working on a project where in a page I'm having a ListBox and every ListBoxItem is an ExpanderView control... everything is working ok, but I'm having problems setting the ExpanderView header to have the maximum width (100% of the available space). I've set

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

on my ListBoxItem, but without any success...

The ExpanderView header template is using a grid view which has 1 row and 2 columns (first should have * width, second should have 100)... so far the first column expands based on the content width and doesn't stretch if needed.

Any idea how I could implement this?

Thank you in advance!

Andrei

Comment: I have an idea on how to debug that: install and use a trial version of http://xamlspy.com/ software, most likely it'll show you which element[s] have incorrect layout attributes so you can fix them with styles and/or templates.

Comment: @Soonts thanks for the comment! I've had very little time to dig into this further the last 2 days, but I'll give XAMLSPY a shot today or tomorrow the latest... never used it before, but heard lots of good things so far about it so hope it will help me :)

Comment: @Soonts mission complete! Thanks for the suggestion! After a bit getting used to XamlSpy I managed to find the issue - had to add the  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" property to a ListBoxItem element in the ExpanderView template which anyway I already had cloned in my XAML. Now how do I mark you comment as answer?